How can I include managedDevices in my detectedApps api response
I am trying to get all the applications installed on all the devices using microsoft graph API
I referred to the stackoverflow question above, but when I tried it, the detectedapps API response contained an empty manageddevices field, even though it showed a device count.
I used following request to get all apps and device ids
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/detectedApps?$expand=managedDevices
Output:
    {
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "displayName": " Chess ",
      "version": "2022.11.01 (2024.11.01)",
      "sizeInByte": 0,
      "deviceCount": 1,
      "publisher": "",
      "platform": "ios",
      "managedDevices": []
    },

managedDevices is always empty
